# Is there a way to workaround this pushd bug?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pushd

Despite it is not documented `pushd` accepts wildcards (when command extensions are turned on). But does not work as I expect and seems buggy. When a [wildcard](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) expression is passed pushd gets all files(!) and folders that apply the pattern in alphabetical order and tries to enter the first item in the list - without checking if it is folder or file:

```
C:>break>a1

C:>md a2

C:>pushd "a*"
The directory name is invalid.

C:>md b1

C:>pushd "b>"

C:\b1>
```

Is there way to force `pushd` to enter the first *directory* that is like the passed the wildcard expression.Things like `b*\` or `b*\nul` does not work.
Looks like the only way is to list directories with `DIR` command, to get the first one and then pass it to the `pushd`:

```
@echo off

set "mask=b?"

for /f "tokens=*" %%# in ('dir /b /a:d /o:-n "%mask%"') do @set the_dir=%%#

pushd %the_dir%
```

But this does not look convenient for usage from command line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this "feature" was accidental.  I doubt there's any way to make it work the way you want.  This functionality is deep in the parsing guts of cmd.exe, and MSFT won't want to go into the legacy code to fix something like that.

Comment: [Pushd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490978.aspx) does not support wildcards. You are essentially asking, how to use a command outside its specification. The answer to that is simple: Don't.

Comment: @IInspectable - the most powerful batch techniques use things not covered by MS documentation (you can consider them as 'hacks'). I don't see why can't abuse `pushd` if it can be useful.

Comment: I don't consider a tool that comes with a disclaimer along the lines of *"Can stop working at any time - we don't know when"* particularly useful.

Comment: @npocmaka: it could be argued that the most powerful batch technique is to forget batch and use a real language if you need to do anything more complex than launching a few executables in sequence.

Comment: Me: "Doctor, it hurts when I use wildcards with PUSHD." Doctor: "Don't do that."

Comment: Rest of the world: "Don't use Batch files! Use any _real programming language_". We Batch file adventurers: "You have not idea of the huge amount of fun you are loosing that you'll never get from any other better defined language; for example: [macros with parameters](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4083), [output color text](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4881), animated games like [Snake](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741), [Tetris](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6812), and a long et cetera plus all future discoveries".

Comment: The `for /F` solution - or rather, `for /D` - is fine for batch files.  If you're on the command line, just press TAB and the wildcard will be expanded to the first matching directory.  If that's not the one you want, press TAB again and you'll get the next matching directory.  (For built-in commands, tab completion knows whether to look for a file or directory.)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting! I just tested `cd` command and it works in the same way. There is no way to "sort" names so folder names comes before file names, but if all your folders have *not* extensions and all your files does have they, you may use the [undocumented "<" wild-card](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6207) to do so:

```
break > a1.txt
md a2
pushd "a<"
```

Comment: Didn't come to me to test `CD`. Great idea with "<" - it will work in most of the cases.